# Excel - Split and save workbook sheets to multiple books based on Single Cell value

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first post as previously I have been able to search this, and other forums to help get answers and write the macro's I need but I have not been able to find an answer that helps solve my current need. Any help/suggestion is much appreciated.

I have a workbook with a over 100 sheets. Each sheet has the same format, and  cell B10 in each sheet contains a name. Using VBA, I need to be able to move all sheets with the same name in cell B10 to their own new workbook and save based on the name. I should end up with 12 workbooks each with a differing number of sheets.

So far I can extract all sheets to their own files but have not been able to figure out how  to group them and save. I think I should be be able to do this with some combination of a Loop and/or Array I just can't quite make it work. Below is what I have so far:

```
Sub Deaggregate()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Copy
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Range("B3").Value & " " & ws.Name & "      " & ws.Range("B4").Value & " " & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"
wb.Close False
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Thanks again for any help/suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

1. Loop through all sheets and add every unique cell b10 name to an array
2. For each unique name in the array ..

2.1 create a new workbook 
eg
Dim newwb as Workbook
set newwb = workbooks.add

2.2 loop through all   the sheets moving each sheet that has the same B10 name to the new workbook.

for each sht in Thisworkbook

if sht.range('B10').value =

.. use macro record to find out the copy to move a sheet to another workbook.
  .. you need to right click on the sheet and choose "move or copy"

next sht

2.3 save the new workbook.

PS. Sorry there's not more code here, but I think this will help a bit